# Angular Firebase auth

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to learn angularfire and add some auth to my site. But it doesn't work as expected. I can't understand why this part isn't working dynamically

```
@HostBinding('class') classes = (this.isLoggedIn())
    ? 'navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top navbar-dark bg-dark'
    : 'navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top navbar-light bg-light';
```

It works once at init. But then nothing is happening.
This is my service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  private userDetails: firebase.User = null;

  constructor(
    private _firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.user = _firebaseAuth.authState;

    this.user.subscribe(
      user => {
        if (user) {
          this.userDetails = user;
          console.log(this.userDetails);
        } else {
          this.userDetails = null;
        }
      }
    );
  }

  signInWithFacebook() {
    return this._firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(
      new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
    );
  }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.userDetails != null;
  }

  logOut(): void {
    this._firebaseAuth.auth.signOut()
    .then(res => this.router.navigate(['/']));
    console.log('logged out');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that it's just called once -- you gotta have an observable or something that will fire an event to set classes? IsLoggedIn() is just a function, on NgOnit probably just gets invoked once and then never again.

Comment: Meanwhile in template there is a `<li *ngIf="this.isLoggedIn()" class="nav-item navbar-text">` which works as it should. When component is loaded nothing is displayed. Few moments later FirebaseAuth updates it's state (already logged in and it receives the data) and component is shown then.

Comment: But if you update the login status without changing away from the component, does it still update the template?

Comment: I change nothing. Just waiting few seconds till FirebaseAuth gets user data since I was logged in before. (Just reload page and component updates and `logout` button is shown but class isn't changed)

Comment: Shouldn't have to reload the app, I think maybe use observables and listen to if loggedIn or not in either the component using subscribe and then unsubscribing, or in the template using async pipe. <li *ngIf="this.isLoggedIn() | async"></lI>

Comment: As I said component work as expected. It updates its state without any `async` pipe. Meanwhile `@HostBinding` experiencing some issues with the same function. Moreover I'm not quite sure how to make an observable that would be in the service and be exposed to component.

Comment: You can use Subjects and derive observables from them
private subject = new Subject();
public obsForComponent = Observable.from(this.subject);

then subscribe to obsForComponent, and set new obs using subject.next(whateverHeretoEmit)

Comment: Worked around via asking for `this.user !== null` instead of `this.userDetails` since user is already an observable. Could I ask you in chat room about logics of working with FireBase? I'm a newbie to it and cannot find exactly what I need. (need advice about just logics of handling my idea not the code)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174050/discussion-between-sergey-and-taranjit-kang).